# Test Angular service

Tags: angular, typescript

Here's a method inside a service that I need to test:

```
public async getLoyaltyRewards(): Promise<IReward[]> {
    return this.sessionmApi.getUserOffers().then((offer) => {
      if (!offer) {
        return [];
      }

      if (offer.user_offers) {
        offer.user_offers.forEach((u) => {
          u.barcode = this.state.getValue().appState.sessionmUser.id;
        });
      }

      return offer.user_offers;
    });
  }
```

Here is my attempt to test, I'm confused about how to manage the condition inside and how to return the value.

```
fit('return get user offers - get loyalty rewards', (doneFn) =>{
  const spygetUserOffers = spyOn(service['sessionmApi'], 'getUserOffers').and.returnValue(Promise.resolve(MockOffer));
  //const spySessionmApiPurchaseReward = spyOn(service['sessionmApi'], 'purchaseReward').and.returnValue(Promise.resolve(MockUserOffer));
  service.getLoyaltyRewards().then((data)=>{
    expect(data).toBeInstanceOf(Array)    
    expect(data).toEqual([MockIreward])    
    //expect(spygetUserOffers).toHaveBeenCalled()
    doneFn()
  })
})
```

Thanks to Vaira: This first test works fine now:

```
fit('should return empty array when offer is undefined', (doneFn) => {
  const mockOffer = undefined // you have to set it undefined as variable
  // sessionmApi need to be passed correctly
  const spygetUserOffers = spyOn(service['sessionmApi'], 'getUserOffers').and.returnValue(Promise.resolve(mockOffer));
  service.getLoyaltyRewards().then((data) => {
      expect(data).toBeInstanceOf(Array)
      expect(data).toEqual([])
      expect(spygetUserOffers).toHaveBeenCalled()
      doneFn()
  })
});
```

But in this second option I don't know why is not allowed, I think I'm passing the correct value (offer.user_offers), this is the error in the editor: *"Argument of type 'Promise<UserOffer[]>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Promise'.
Type 'UserOffer[]' is missing the following properties from type 'Offer':"..* but the return in that condition is : offer.user_offers

```
fit('should return undefined if user_offers is not defined', (doneFn) => {
  const mockUserOffer = MockOffer.user_offers ; // you have to set it without the required property
  // sessionmApi need to be passed correctly
  const spygetUserOffers = spyOn(service['sessionmApi'], 'getUserOffers').and.returnValue(Promise.resolve(mockUserOffer));
  service.getLoyaltyRewards().then((data) => {
      expect(data).toEqual(undefined)
      expect(spygetUserOffers).toHaveBeenCalled()
      doneFn()
  })
});
```

Comment: The Angular docs provide extensive guidance on testing in various scenarios: https://angular.io/guide/testing.

Answer (score -1):

You will update the value of the `MockOffer` every time in diffetnt fit use case,
eg: nullMockOffer = null
or  mockOfferWithoutUser_offers = {}
or  Mockoffer = {user_offers: []}

All these different values of mock offer will run different condition inside the code block and hence produce different output that you can validate

```
fit('should return empty array when offer is undefined', (doneFn) => {
    const mockOffer = undefined // you have to set it undefined as variable
    // sessionmApi need to be passed correctly
    const spygetUserOffers = spyOn(sessionmApi, 'getUserOffers').and.returnValue(Promise.resolve(mockOffer));
    service.getLoyaltyRewards().then((data) => {
        expect(data).toBeInstanceOf(Array)
        expect(data).toEqual([])
        expect(spygetUserOffers).toHaveBeenCalled()
        doneFn()
    })
});

fit('should return undefined if user_offers is not defined', (doneFn) => {
    const mockOffer = { user_offers : undefined }; // you have to set it without the required property
    // sessionmApi need to be passed correctly
    const spygetUserOffers = spyOn(sessionmApi, 'getUserOffers').and.returnValue(Promise.resolve(mockOffer));
    service.getLoyaltyRewards().then((data) => {
        expect(data).toEqual(undefined)
        expect(spygetUserOffers).toHaveBeenCalled()
        doneFn()
    })
});
```

Comment: Ok, I understand that, but my  problem is how can I "enter" to the if conditions one by one to make the tests and then return the correct Mock :(

Comment: @MarcosGalaviz I have added two example

Comment: I really appreciate your help, now my first test works great, but not the second, I updated my comment with my code, if you have a minute I really appreciate any suggestion

Comment: I am not sure what is "MockOffer"?, your code is not working because you are trying to pass "user_offers" instead of the object "Offer" that contains property of "user_offers" as a property.

You should understand that "Promise.resolve(<enter object of offer>)"

Comment: Thank you your comments help me a lot with this test.